# see the content of a .bson file using java

Tags: java, mongodb, parsing, bson

I have a very large `.bson` file.

Now I have two question:

1. How can I see the content of that file? (I know it can do with **"bsondump"**, but this command is slow, specialy for large database) (In fact I want to see the structure of that file)
2. How can I see the content of that file using java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily read/parse a bson file in Java using a `BSONDecoder` instance such as `BasicBSONDecoder` or `DefaultBSONDecoder`. These classes are included in mongo-java-driver.

Here's a simple example of a Java implementation of `bsondump`.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.bson.BSONDecoder;
import org.bson.BSONObject;
import org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder;



public class BsonDump {

    public void bsonDump(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(filename);
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        BSONDecoder decoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();
        int count = 0;
        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {

                BSONObject obj = decoder.readObject(inputStream);
                if(obj == null){
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(obj);
                count++;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        System.err.println(String.format("%s objects read", count));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        if (args.length < 1) {
            //TODO usage
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected <bson filename> argument");
        }
        String filename = args[0];
        BsonDump bsonDump = new BsonDump();
        bsonDump.bsonDump(filename);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am very thankful, if you can provide more information. Also I am thankful if you put complete code.

Comment: There's not a whole lot else to it. I updated, adding full source with the main() method.

Comment: nice answer indeed +1

Comment: BsonDump is the source/class from above,  you need to copy that code into your project or write a similar class to do your specific inspection of the bson file.

Comment: It looks like you probably named your class BSON_Reader, so just change that line to be BSON_Reader reader = new BSON_Reader(); and the following line(s) in main() to use reader rather than bsonDump.

Comment: BTW, most standard Java code conventions typically do not use underscores for class names. You might want to consider naming your class BsonReader or BSONReader instead.

Comment: Thanks, but during running I faced to an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected <bson filename> argument
 at bson_reader.BSON_Reader.main(BSON_Reader.java:50)
Java Result: 1. *****  Also I thankful if you can put a simple code to just read and show data in the "main" instead of //TODO Usage

Comment: Yup, you need to pass the filename/path argument when you run, or hard code for now.

Comment: I am sorry, i have a question, using the readObject method do i read each object or all the objects (at once) of the file ? I am working on something that uses this but works with large bson files and loading these files in the RAM entirely is impossible watching your answers seems that it reads object by object but i am not 100% sure.